# How to determine the Jacobian when solving a nonlinear system by Newton-Raphson method

Tags: floating-accuracy, nonlinear-functions, newtons-method

I am trying to solve some nonlinear systems by Newton's method and the solution accuracy is very important to my problem.

1. without using the symbolic computation softwares, how can I compute the Jacobian of a general nonlinear system of polynomials via C++ or other similar programming languages? The difficulties for me are mainly:

   - as accurate as symbolic Jacobian
   - an algorithm suitable for general nonlinear system cases
   - only dependent on C++ or similar programming languages;
2. If I have to use finite difference method to obtain an approximate Jacobian, how the step size chosen would affect the final solution accuracy? how to determine the step size so that I can obtain best solution accuracy under the same computation precision level? How to determine (quantitatively) the effects of approximate Jacobian on the accuracy of the final solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the idea of dual numbers, there exist several example implementations in C++. Evaluating the functions using appropriately initialized dual numbers results in the evaluation of one directional derivative. Repeat this for all coordinate directions.

For a nice introduction, see Piponi: AD, C++ and Photogrammetry (http://el.mdu.edu.tw/datacos/09820722022O/paper.pdf)

If L is the effort to evaluate the functions, one directional derivative costs about 3*L, the full jacobian 3n*L. If one were to combine all the directions in one evaluation, this reduces to (1+2n)*L. But by then we have entered the realm of automatic or algorithmic differentiation.

Look for FADBAD/TADIFF for an easy implementation, for really fast codes one uses code transformations as provided by the Tapenade project. ADOL-C is in between, more automatic than Tapenade, faster than FADBAD.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself by using finite difference approximation of Jacobian;

It seems there is essentially no difference when solving a nonlinear system via symbolic Jacobian or finite difference Jacobian in either efficiency or accuracy.

The only difference is: symbolic Jacobian requires less step to reach desired convergence; if Jacobian can be provided, then it will be faster.

Comment: There are other advantages.  With blind finite-difference schemes it can be difficult to take advantage of sparsity (e.g. many wasted function evaluations), whereas if a symbolic Jacobian is available then it will obviously expose the sparsity directly.